# User-Entered value for Array Size doesn't actually change the array's size. [Java]

Tags: java, arrays

So as the title says, I'm trying to get a user inputted size to my array, yet every time I run the program it does not change the array size. I'm pretty sure its something to do with my constructors but i'm not positive. Any help would be appreciated!

Class 1 (Numbers)

```
package lab1;

import java.util.Random;

public class Numbers {
public int size;
public Integer[]arr = new Integer [size];

public Numbers () {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = new Integer(i);
    }
}   

public Numbers(int size){
    this.size = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = new Integer(i);
    }
}
public void generateNumbers(){
    System.out.println(arr.length);
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
    }
}
public int count(int val){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] == val){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        builder.append(arr[i]).append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();

}
}
```

Class 2 (Lab1)

```
package lab1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab1 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Numbers numbers =  new Numbers();
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menu = 1;
    while (menu != 0){
        System.out.println("1 to create array of new size\n"
                + "2 to generate random numbers into array\n"
                + "3 to count a value\n"
                + "4 to display array\n"
                + "0 to quit\n");
        menu = input.nextInt();
        switch (menu) {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Enter new size:\n");
            int size = input.nextInt();
            size = numbers.size;
            System.out.println("Array has been generated of size: " + numbers.size + "\n");
            break;
        case 2: 
            numbers.generateNumbers();
            System.out.println("Numbers have been generated\n");
            break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.println("Enter number to search for:\n");
            int num = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("There are " + numbers.count(num) + " of the         number " + num);
            break;
        case 4: 
            System.out.println(numbers.toString());
            break;          
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: you're not changing the value of `size` in your instance of `Numbers`:

```
size = numbers.size;
```

This updates the local variable `size`, not the member variable of `numbers`, overwriting the value you just read from the scanner. To update the member variable with that value:

```
numbers.size = size;
```

Second problem: you're not actually changing the size of the array.

The array is created when the instance of the class is initialized:

```
public int size;
public Integer[]arr = new Integer [size];
```

At the time it is created, `size` is zero, so `arr` is initialized to be a zero-length array. Changing the value of `size` won't change the size of `arr` automatically.

You will need to create a new instance and assign it to the `arr` member variable. If you are specifying this at construction time:

```
public Numbers(int size){
    this.size = size;
    this.arr = new Integer[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = new Integer(i);
    }
}
```

Note that because `size == 0` initially, your default constructor (`public Numbers()`) does nothing: the body of the for loop `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){` is never executed, because `i == 0` and `size == 0` initially, so `0 < 0` is false. You should probably just remove the default constructor, so you *always* have to specify a value for `size` to construct the instance.

If you remove the default constructor, you can remove the inline initialization of `arr`:

```
public Integer[]arr;
```

since a non-null value will be assigned in the constructor.

Alternatively, if you only ever use `Numbers` in the code you've given, you can get rid of *both* constructors, and just declare your fields as:

```
public int size = 0;
public Integer[] arr = new Integer[0];
```

However, in your code, you are trying to change the length of the array after it has been constructed. In this case, you would need to create a new array whenever you change the value of `size`, for example:

```
numbers.size = size;
numbers.arr = Arrays.copyOf(numbers.arr, numbers.size);
```

`Arrays.copyOf` will appropriately truncate your array or pad it with zeros, depending upon whether `size` is less than or greater than the current length of the array.

Note that it would be usual to encapsulate such changes in a method on `Numbers`:

```
public void setSize(int size) {
  this.size = size;
  this.arr = Arrays.copyOf(this.arr, size);
}
```

and make the fields `private`, so that they can only be updated by methods in `Numbers`:

```
private int size;
private Integer[]arr;
```

Finally, note that `size` is redundant: you can remove it, and simply use `arr.length` instead.

Comment: Use `new Numbers(0)` then. But if you never call it with a value other than `0`, you can simplify the code by removing the constructors and initializing the fields; see my edited answer.

Comment: This helps a lot, great response! Thanks so much. The only thing is now i've removed my default constructor I need a parameter when creating the object in the Lab1 class.

Here is what I have now:

`
public class Numbers {
 public int size;
 public Integer[]arr;
 
 public Numbers(int size){
  this.size = size;
  this.arr = new Integer[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
   arr[i] = new Integer(i);
  }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this block of code:

```
  public Integer[]arr = new Integer [size];
```

Removing this belock below because not necessary:

```
public Numbers () {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     arr[i] = new Integer(i);
   }
}
```

Mantaine this below:

```
 public Numbers(int size) {
   this.size = size;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     arr[i] = new Integer(i);
   }
 }
```

With:

```
  public Integer[] arr; // here declared

  public Numbers(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    arr = new Integer[size]; //here initialize it
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      arr[i] = new Integer(i);
    }
 }
```

Like this you give the size of array with user input.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you create the int array.
When you call new Numbers() the array size of the created object is 0.
Then when you set size with numbers.size you only change the size variable you do not change the size of the array.
What you what is to create a setSize(int newSize) functions which sets the array size and resizes the array. For instance if the new size is bigger then copy all the elements (values) into new array which has a few extra spaces if the new size is smaller then the current then copy the max number of elements that can fit into the new array if they are the sam size there is no need to change anything.